# Trigger Lambda function when future timestamp stored in Dynamodb arrives

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I am coming from relational database background, and I am trying to experiment with AWS services. I have a dynamoDb table with following record:

```
 ------------------------------------------------
 | Id | Start Timestamp | End Timestamp | Data  |
 ------------------------------------------------
```

Both start and end timestamps are future timestamps and I want to trigger a AWS Lambda function when start timestamp or end timestamp arrives.

To clarify by 'arrives' I mean when start/end timestamp is equal to current timestamp, is it possible to trigger a Lambda function when this happens.

Is it possible by DynamoDb streams? I wanted a reactive way to solve this problem not the usual way to poll the Db and trigger Lambda function when actual timestamp arrives.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

There's no way to do this without constantly polling DynamoDB to see if you have arrived at a certain time, and then triggering the Lambda function if you have. In other words there is no mechanism that is going to automatically initiate anything based on a timestamp you have stored in DynamoDB. You would have to implement that mechanism yourself by polling DynamoDB regularly and comparing the timestamps to the current time.

There is a mechanism to trigger Lambda functions at a given date/time, but it isn't driven by DynamoDB. It is [AWS Lambda Scheduled Events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html). You could programmatically create those schedules. If you want that to be driven by DynamoDB then you could setup a separate Lambda function that is triggered by new DynamoDB records, which would take the timestamp in the new record and create a Lambda Scheduled Event from that.

Comment: Thanks Mark, dynamically creating lambda schedules looks like a way to go.

Comment: @kabeerkhan if you could share with us how you did it, that'd be great.

Comment: I am trying to do something similar inside aws amplify, I want the 'Post' to delete itself when the given timestamp hits. One way to do this is to use @ttl (timetolive) feature provided in dynamoDB but thats not reliable as it may delete it after ~48hrs.